# is it possible to save a file as static html file with header information?

Tags: javascript, html, http-headers

I want to give my widget customers a file to upload to their servers. I dont want it to depend on server side technology (PHP, ASP etc...) so I wont have to maintain variation.

The file contains html and javascript (it does redirect based on local cookies).
I also need this file to have a special header (P3P privacy policy).

how can I create a HTML file which contains header information that customers can upload to their servers?

Answer (score 2):

HTML has nothing to do with header information. Headers are a property of HTTP, which is the protocol most commonly used to send HTML to the browser. If you want to store header information, this would need to be stored separately from the document and read by the web server or a server-side script which would send the appropriate headers to the browser.

However, many HTTP headers have an equivalent which can be embedded in HTML. In the case of P3P, you can use a `link` tag to specify the URL to an external policy file stores the P3P info for that doucment.

```
<link rel="P3Pv1" href="some uri">
```

Note that this won't be particularly efficient if you have a large number of files each with different policies since P3P policies are generally fairly small and will require an extra request from the client. But I believe this is the best you can get without any integration with the specific sever used by the client.